# Can't get longitude and latitude in telegram-bot-ruby

Tags: ruby, geolocation, telegram-bot

I have a problem. Where I must add `message.location.latitude` command to get the user's location after getting message with location. I have to replace geocode with user's location requested earlier. Thank's for advice.

```
require 'open_weather'
require 'telegram/bot'

options_OpenWeather = { units: "metric", APPID: "some text" }
options_Bot = 'some keys'

Telegram::Bot::Client.run(options_Bot) do |bot|

bot.listen do |message|
  kb = [
        Telegram::Bot::Types::KeyboardButton.new(text: 'Show me your location', request_location: true)           
       ]
       markup = Telegram::Bot::Types::ReplyKeyboardMarkup.new(keyboard: kb)

       pp weather = OpenWeather::Current.geocode(53.11, 23.36, options_OpenWeather)
  case message.text
    when '/start'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Hello, #{message.from.first_name}!")
    when '/end'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Bye, #{message.from.first_name}!")     
    when '/help'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Available commands:
      /start
      /end
      /help
      /hi
      /weather
      /test")
    when '/hi' 
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: 'Hey!', reply_markup: markup)         
     when '/weather'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Weather in your location: #{weather["main"]["temp"]} celcius, #{weather["main"]["pressure"]} hPa. Humidity is #{weather["main"]["humidity"]}% ")                    
    when '/test'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text:"I'm testing command")
    else
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "I don't understand you ")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add this before your `case` and move all this handling weather stuff to some separate function. But I fell I'm not anwsering your question and writing here some obvious stuff. You can look at [my bot's](https://github.com/iansowinski/poznan_bot/blob/master/bot/telegram_bot.rb) front-end. It's quite old and messy implementation I did a long time ago, but It works. Maybe you can do also some caching with redis if you want your users to save locations and just send comands after they set their location for the first time.

```rb
def(lat, lng)
  return OpenWeather::Current.geocode(lat, lng, options_OpenWeather)
  ...
end

if message.location != nil
  weather = handle_weather_from_location(
    message.location.lattitude
    message.location.longitude
  )
  bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Weather in your location: #{weather["main"]["temp"]} celcius, #{weather["main"]["pressure"]} hPa. Humidity is #{weather["main"]["humidity"]}% ")                    
end
```